# linq left outer join on lists

Tags: linq

I have 3 lists, a list of payments to users, a list of taxes paid on that same payment, a list of state taxes paid on that same payment.

the problem is, taxes or state taxes may not exist for each payment, so i need each individual payment matched up with both the taxes or state taxes that were paid, but continue to show up if one or both of those do not exist. this is the particular query in question as i have it right now

```
    var joinEverything = 
    from IP in IndividualPaymentsList
    join TD in TaxDetailsList.DefaultIfEmpty()
        on IP.UserId equals TD.UserId
        where IP.WeekEndDate == TD.WeekEndDate
    join ST in StateTaxDetailsList.DefaultIfEmpty()
        on IP.UserId equals ST.UserId
        where IP.WeekEndDate == ST.WeekEndDate
    select new 
    {
        IP.UserId,
        FedTax = TD.CheckAmount,
        StateTax = ST.CheckAmount,
        IP.CheckAmount,
    };
```

currently if a record does not exist in, for example, state taxes i get a 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' rather than just accepting the null as the value in ST.CheckAmount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the `DefaultIfEmpty()` thing which is fine, but then you're trying to retrieve properties of objects that are set to this default value, e.g. `TD.UserId` means that you're calling null.UserId.

Below is my attempt to make it work - however, I don't really have data to test it, so I might have messed up the syntax somewhere or I might try to access a variable that's out of range - give it a try and let me know if you run into problems:

```
var joinEverything = 
    from IP in IndividualPaymentsList
    join TD in TaxDetailsList
        on IP.UserId equals TD.UserId into group1
        from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where g1 == null || (IP.WeekEndDate == g1.WeekEndDate)
    join ST in StateTaxDetailsList
        on IP.UserId equals ST.UserId into group2
        from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where g2 == null || IP.WeekEndDate == g2.WeekEndDate
    select new 
    {
        IP.UserId,
        FedTax = (g1 != null ? g1.CheckAmount : String.Empty), // or your default value for the type
        StateTax = (g2 != null ? g2.CheckAmount : String.Empty),
        IP.CheckAmount,
    };
```

Comment: I still get the error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the line `where g2.WeekEndDate == null || (IP.WeekEndDate == g2.WeekEndDate)` (it still works on g1, since that has records)

Comment: would the default value for WeekEndDate be null ? What is the type of this column

Comment: actually, i got it, your answer was 95% there.
`where g2.WeekEndDate == null || (IP.WeekEndDate == g2.WeekEndDate)` 
needed to be
`where g2 == null || (IP.WeekEndDate == g2.WeekEndDate)`

Comment: Yep, I've just noticed this too! sorry about that :-)